# Do I need OAuth process if my GAE app should use Analytics API?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I would like to display on my GAE website a number of daily users of my android application (tracked with Google Analytics), both are under the same account. I wanted to use Analytics API for this. I am reading [Hello Analytics API tutorial](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/hello-analytics-api) and looks like I need OAuth to authorize my app to get the data from Analytics. It looks quite complex, is there any easy way (like getting some token and using it)?

Looks like I need [service account](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount) (for server to server applications), but I don't understand how to modify [starter application](https://developers.google.com/qs/c/gen?api=analytics&apikey=&client_secret_url=https://code.google.com/apis/quick/b/0/client-secrets?project=64436293404&client=64436293404-3qr86dksb9ibejf1opn7li6em336pomv.apps.googleusercontent.com&xsrf=AL254vRj8qO5in5VQ5ksc6ojTvspC0Qqqw:1391865901890&key=UNyt4MPgtY_PFjeJUlAtq8D4Osw6MTM5MTg2NTc5NjUyMTY5ODQ0Mg==&lang_plat=python_appengine_skeleton&project=64436293404&version=v3) (taken [there](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/installation)) to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only want to access data that you own, using a service account is a good idea.

How ever the starter application you linked is for working with a normal OAuth2 and its not the same as the code for a service account.

I haven't done this in python myself before, but i found an example that should get you started.  You will need to change it slightly because the scopes are for Google+ not Google analytics.   [create the service in python on GAE](https://gist.github.com/vircheck/6292176)

If you have any problems changing it to work with Google Analtyics let me know i should be able to help with that. Even if i cant test the python code myself.

Answer (score 0):

There is much simpler way to pass authorization - see [App Identity doc](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/appidentity/#Python_Asserting_identity_to_Google_APIs). See also [Java example](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/gdataAppEngine) how to access Analytics data from the GAE.

Another useful link is [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/google_app_engine).